# Is it true or false that $\lvert P([0, 1]) \setminus P((0, 1)) \rvert > \lvert P(\mathbb{N}) \rvert$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true or false that $\lvert P([0, 1]) \setminus P((0, 1)) \rvert > \lvert P(\mathbb{N}) \rvert$ ?

I need a hint because I don't see a way to solve this

Comment: What is the function $P$?

Comment: $P$ is a power set

Comment: You're asking about the number of subsets of $[0,1]$ that are not subsets of $(0,1)$.  For every subset $S$ of $(0,1)$, there are these three subsets of $[0,1]$ that are not subsets of $(0,1)$: first $S\cup\{0\}$, then $S\cup\{1\}$, then $S\cup\{0,1\}$.  Thus there are three times as many members of $P([0, 1]) \setminus P((0, 1))$ as there are of $P((0,1))$.  Do you know what $3$ times an infinite cardinality is? $\qquad$

Comment: All I know is that $א \cdot א = א$

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's true: $|P([0,1])|\ge |P([0,1]) \setminus P((0,1))|=|{0}\cup P((0,1))|+|{1}\cup P((0,1))|\ge|P((0,1))|$ since those two cardinals are both equal to $|P((0,1))|$ (by ${0}\cup P((0,1)$ I mean the set $\{{0}\cup A;A\in P((0,1))\}$; similar for the other one). It shouldn't be too hard to see that $|P((0,1))|=P([0,1])$ so that in fact $|P([0,1]) \setminus P((0,1))|=|P([0,1])|=|P((0,1))|$.

We also have $|P(\mathbb{N})|=|(0,1)|<|P([0,1])|$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following is an injection
$$
\mathcal P((0,1)) \to \mathcal P([0,1]) \setminus \mathcal P( (0,1)), X \mapsto X \cup \{0\}.
$$

Hence $\operatorname{card}(\mathcal P([0,1]) \setminus \mathcal P( (0,1))) = \operatorname{card}{(\mathcal P((0,1)))} =  \operatorname{card}(\mathcal P(\mathbb R)) = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} > 2^{\aleph_0} = \operatorname{card}(\mathbb R) = \operatorname{card}(\mathcal P(\mathbb N))$.

Comment: The inequality is given by Cantor's Theorem: For any set $X$, we have that $\operatorname{card}(X) < \operatorname{card}(\mathcal P (X))$.